# Same socket speed is 66% slower on a new thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, sockets

This is crazy! I heard Python threads are slow but this is beyond normal.

Here is the pseudo-code:

```
class ReadThread:

    v = []
    def __init__(self, threaded = True):
        self.v = MySocket('127.0.0.1')
        if threaded:
            thread.start_new_thread(self._scan, ())

    def read(self):
        t0 = datetime.now()
        self.v.read('SomeVariable')
        t = datetime.now()
        dt = (t-t0).total_seconds()

        print dt

    def _scan(self):
        while True:
            self.read()
```

If I run the read() in a while loop in the main-thread as this:

```
r = ReadThread(threaded = False)
while True:
    r.read()
```

dt is about 78 ms with small variation. Now if I run it in a new thread like this:

```
r = ReadThread(threaded = True)
while True:
    pass
```

dt is about 130 ms with +-10ms variance!

Why is it so slow? Am I doing something really wrong? It's the same thing just in a new thread!

MySocket() is is an object that uses a socket to read/write variables to a server and read() just gets some variable for the test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to reproduce this problem locally without knowing what `MySocket` is, and the full example. However, I can try guessing, that the problem is this cycle:

```
while True:
    pass
```

It is **VERY** CPU-consuming. The CPU literally goes around all the time, taking the CPU cycles to itself, and not letting the socket to work.

Contrary, the socket read operations are usually blocking and idling for the data to arrive, so they consume almost no CPU.

In the first example, you run your socket while nothing else eats CPU. In the second example, the main thread consumes 1 CPU completely.

Try replacing this cycle with a usual idling operation, e.g. `time.sleep(60)`. So the main thread will idle for 60s while the socket thread will read and process data.

```
r = ReadThread(threaded = True)
time.sleep(60)
```

What will be the measuring in that case then?

Comment: In the real code each thread requests values by writting in a list. Another thread reads the list and writes the answers. It is contanly monitoring for new requests. The consumer threads constnatly monitor for the responses. I found that a small time.sleep() does the trick but what would be other ways to solve the problem better? Events perhaps?

Comment: You should learn the thread synchronization primitives (https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/threading.html). I think, `Event` and/or `Condition` are the most fitting for your use-case, depending on how many threads need to react.

Comment: Event seems to fit quite well with the threads that request the data, they could just send an event also in the request. I am not sure how to wake up the thread that uses the socket though. If I have a common event for the socket thread then thread1 can wake it up and by the time it fnishes thread2 also tried to wake it up and failed. I can use a lock but I want to ensure requests go in order. They go now. I need to give it some thought.